# (DRF) ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ''. Unable to pass in id to the url

Tags: reactjs, django, django-views, axios

I am writing a custom function to add favourite to `Thread` model. The function should expect an id pass in to the `get_object_or_404`.

```
@csrf_exempt
def add_favourites(request, id, *args, **kwargs):
    thread = get_object_or_404(Thread, id=id)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        if thread.liked.filter(username=request.user.username).exists():
            thread.liked.remove(request.user.username)
        
        else:
            thread.liked.add(request.user.username)
```

and I have my `url.py` like this to receive an id from axios url:

```
path('api/public/favourites/<int:id>/', add_favourites, name='add_favourites'),
```

However, when I perform the axios post request like this:

```
axiosInstance.post(`api/public/favourites/4/`)
```

It should be receiving `id = 4`, but it always return error:

```
(DRF) ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.
```

Anybody has an idea whats wrong with my code? Much Thanks.

Comment: Does any other url use the `add_favourites`  view?

Answer (score 0):

```
thread = get_object_or_404(Thread, pk=id)
```

Did you try this?

Comment: nothing changed, got the same error

Comment: maybe problem with migrations

Comment: still the save after deleted the whole database and made migrations